# How can I write a factory for services that implement a generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics, service-factory

Given a set of services that each implement a generic interface where the type parameters all have a common base, how can I write a factory method to return an instance of one of these services? There seems to be no way to write a return type for the factory method.

Here is the sample code, with the problematic method at the bottom:

```cs
public abstract class Base
{
    public int BaseProp { get; set; }
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    public int DerivedProp1 { get; set; }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public int DerivedProp2 { get; set; }
}

public interface IHandleStuff<T> where T : Base
{
    T GetStuff();
    void DoStuff(T t);
}

public class Service1 : IHandleStuff<Derived1>
{
    public Derived1 GetStuff() => new();
    public void DoStuff(Derived1 t){}
}

public class Service2 : IHandleStuff<Derived2>
{
    public Derived2 GetStuff() => new();
    public void DoStuff(Derived2 t){}
}

public class Consumer
{
    public void DoStuff(Base t)
    {
        var service = GetServiceFor(t);
        service.DoStuff(t);
    }

    private IHandleStuff<Base> GetServiceFor(Base t)
    {
        return t.BaseProp switch
        {
            1 => new Service1(), // Cannot convert expression type 'Service1' to return type 'IHandleStuff<Base>'
            2 => new Service2(), // An explicit cast to IHandleStuff<Base> compiles but fails at runtime
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
        };
    }
}
```

**Update**:

Someone pointed out in a comment (now deleted) that the issue in the above code can be resolved by making the `DoStuff` and `GetServiceFor` methods in the `Consumer` class generic.  This works, but at some point in the real code we have to call into this from a non-generic method which knows only the base type. So the suggestion only defers the problem.

Comment: There is no way to do this unless you write an adapter that has `DoStuff(Base)` as a signature, or you're willing to go `dynamic`. By making the type only known at runtime you must necessarily give up compile-time safety, the only choice left is where. As for a common return type, either `object` or an empty `IHandleStuff {}` marker interface would do.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks - that was what I was afraid of. We're heading down the adapter route.